# Bootstrap form validation in jQuery instead of plain JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I found this on Bootstrap to use Bootstrap form validation. Why is the example in plain JavaScript instead of jQuery when the rest of Bootstrap scripts are in jQuery?

How can this be done with jQuery?

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#validation

```
<script>
// Example starter JavaScript for disabling form submissions if there are invalid fields
(function() {
  'use strict';
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
    var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
    // Loop over them and prevent submission
    var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
        }
        form.classList.add('was-validated');
      }, false);
    });
  }, false);
})();
</script>
```

Comment: Is this an official part of the Bootstrap source? If it's by a third party, then it's most likely just written in whatever they felt most comfortable with

Comment: No it is from the documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#validation

Answer (score 4):

use Jquery Validation : https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#contact-form').validate({
                rules: {
                    'checkbox': {
                        required: true
                    }
                },
                highlight: function (input) {
                    $(input).addClass('is-invalid');
                },
                unhighlight: function (input) {
                   $(input).removeClass('is-invalid');
                },
                errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                    $(element).next().append(error);
                }
            });
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
   
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.17.0/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


 <form id="contact-form" method="POST" action="/contact">
                                    <div class="form-group">  
                                       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name" id="name" class="form-control"  autocomplete='name' value="" required>
                                        <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email" id="email" class="form-control"  autocomplete='email' value="" required>
                                        <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" id="phone" class="form-control" autocomplete='tel' value="" required>
                                        <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <textarea placeholder="Message" class="form-control" name="message" rows="5" class="form-control" required></textarea>
                                        <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
                                    </div>
                                 


                                    <div class="container-contact-form-btn">
                                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
                                                Send Now
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.needs-validation').on('submit', function(e) {
      if (!this.checkValidity()) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
      }

      $(this).addClass('was-validated');
    });

});
```

Comment: It would be nice to also include an explanation on how what caused the original issue and how your answer helps solve it

Comment: @GMB The question was to convert a piece of plain JavaScript to jQuery. I don't feel it needs any explanation.

Comment: it works for me, but as a way to validate in a form that both passwords are equal.

Answer (score 1):

This example was most likely written in JS as that's what the author of the Bootstrap documentation was most comfortable with. You can convert it to jQuery like this:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  $(window).on('load', function() {
    $('.needs-validation').on('submit', function(e) {
      if (!this.checkValidity()) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
      }

      $(this).addClass('was-validated');
    });
  });
})();
```

Comment: it works for me, but as a way to validate in a form that both passwords are equal.